# $f$ is a linear map from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to $M_k(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra

Define $M_n(C)$ as the linear space over the field $\mathbb{C}$ consisting of all the $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{C}$.

Let $f$ be a linear map from $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ to $M_k(\mathbb{C})$ satisfying the following condition:

if $A$ is a $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix, which by definition is a complex matrix satisfying $A=A^*$, then $f(A)$ is an Hermitian matrix in $M_k(\mathbb{C})$.

Prove that $\forall A$ in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ we have $f(A^*)=f(A)^*$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step consists on showing that the result is true for anti-hermitian matrices, i.e., matrices such that $M=-M^*$. To see this note that $iM$ is hermitian. Then, 
$$
f((iA)^*)=-if(A^*)=f(iA)^*=-if(A)^*.
$$
Once this has been shown, note that any matrix $A$ can be written as the sum of a hermitian and an anti-hermitian matrix:
$$
A=\frac{A+A^*}{2}+\frac{A-A^*}{2}.
$$
The result follows immediately by working through the equation
$$
f(A)^*=f\left(\frac{A+A^*}{2}+\frac{A-A^*}{2}\right)^*.
$$
If you need more details let me know and I'll add them.